# Why is winforms outputting incorrect value for Panel.Width?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I just created a new blank Windows Forms app, and I added a Panel controls to it and docked to the top of the Form. And in the Form1 Shown event I write output the value of panel1.Width, but even when it's size is changed, it still tells me it's only 200 pixels wide.

Why is that?

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine(panel1.Width);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. If I add a docked Panel to a Form, then have a button with a click handler that shows a MessageBox of the Panel's width, each message box shows the correct `Width`. So *where* is your Console.WriteLine being called? In what event?

Comment: Did You put `Console.WriteLine(panel1.Width);` in `Form_Resize`? I just try and while resizing form diff. value showed. btw. I not use `console.writeln` but `label`.

Comment: I just tried with a label and no difference. I also tried outputting value in Panel.Resize instead of Form.Resize and still no difference. I'm so confused about this. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: There is my code (vb, sorry) : `Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize :
        Label1.Text = Panel1.Width.ToString :
    End Sub` ... `Panel1` is docked top. Work fine.

Comment: You'll need to show more code, as I haven't been able to reproduce your described behavior either.

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Explain clearly what that code does, and how that is different from what you want the code to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well seeing as though nobody (including myself) can reproduce this problem and that this is not (as far as I've been able to tell) a known bug, I can only think of one thing...

You're not giving us all of your code, and you are also sub-classing the Panel control.

After InitializeComponent, add this:

```
subClassedPanel.Width = this.Width;
subClassedPanel.Dock = DockStyles.Top;
myPanel = subClassedPanel;
```